# Search a string and print the line if it is found in python

Tags: python, csv, file, file-io, python-re

I'm a beginner in Python. I have a text file `numberstofind.txt` as follows:

```
-49

-56

-62
```

I need to find those numbers in another CSV file `midvalues1.csv` and print the line if they are found. Each number can't be on the same line. *The problem is my script never finds the second number and I know it is in my CSV file.*

```py
import os
import csv
import sys

with open("numberstofind.txt", 'r') as fp: 
    data = ",{0}".format(fp.readline().strip())
    
with open("midvalues1.csv", "r") as csv:
    found = False
    for line in csv:
        if data in line:
            print(line)
            print('Found !')
            f = open("ident1.txt", "w+") 
            f.write(line)
            f.close()
            found = True

if not found: 
    print('Data not found!')
    
with open("numberstofind.txt", 'r') as pd:
    phrasedeux = pd.readlines()
    phrasedeux=phrasedeux[1]
    print(phrasedeux)
    
    with open("midvalues1.csv", "r") as csvd:
        found = False
        for line in csvd:
            if phrasedeux in line:
                print(line)
                print('Found !')
                f = open("ident2.txt", "w+")
                f.write(line)
                f.close()
                found = True
    
if not found: 
    print('Data not found!')
    
with open("numberstofind.txt", 'r') as ph:
    phrasetrois = ph.readlines()
    phrasetrois=phrasetrois[2]
    
    with open("midvalues1.csv", "r") as csv:
        found = False
        for line in csv:
            if phrasetrois in line:
                print(line)
                print('Found !')
                f = open("ident3.txt", "w+")
                f.write(line)
                f.close()
                found = True

if not found: 
    print('Data not found!')
```

Output:

```
876,6,-49,1754,John Doe

Found !
-56

Data not found!
411,6,-62,48,Some other name

Found !
```

`-56` is the number that is never found.

What is the best approach to find each number of my text file into my CSV file and print the line?

I tried this:

```py
import re
import csv

with open("numberstofind.txt", 'r') as d:
    dt = d.readlines()
    dt=dt[1]
    print(dt)

with open('midvalues1.csv', 'r') as csv:
    lines = csv.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if re.search(r'-56', line):
            print(line)
            break
```

It works but I can't predict this number so if I replace `-56` with `dt`

```py
if re.search(dt, line):
```

This doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking text file `numberstofind.txt` as:

```
-49

-56

-62
```

and, CSV file `midvalues1.csv` as:

```
876,6,-49,1754,John Doe
411,6,-56,48,Some other name
411,6,-62,48,Some other other name
```

Try this:

```py
import csv

with open("numberstofind.txt", 'r') as file:
    data = [line.strip() for line in file if line.strip() != '']

for i, number in enumerate(data):
    found = False
    with open('midvalues1.csv', 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if any(number in cell for cell in row):
                line = ','.join(row)
                print(line)
                print(f'Found {number}!')
                f = open(f'ident{i+1}.txt', 'w+')
                f.write(line)
                f.close()
                found = True

    if not found:
        print('Data not found!')
```

Output:

```
876,6,-49,1754,John Doe
Found -49!
411,6,-56,48,Some other name
Found -56!
411,6,-62,48,Some other other name
Found -62!
```

And, three new files are created with the names `ident1.txt`, `ident2.txt`, and `ident3.txt` containing the corresponding rows from the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Open the numbers file **once**, and read each number into a list:

```
numberstofind = []
with open('numberstofind.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        numberstofind.append(line.strip())
```

Then read the csv file line-by-line, and check if each number in the list is in the current csv row:

```
with open("midvalues1.csv", "r") as csv:
    for row in csv:
        for number in numberstofind:
            if number in row:
                print(f'{number}' was found in {row}')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your program, you want to create a new file for every data found and the respective data to be written in the respective file. I'm following the same logic:

```
txt = open("numberstofind.txt", 'r')

#list of lines in numberstofind.txt
txt_data = txt.readlines()

#close txt_data to avoid data loss
txt.close()

csv = open('midvalues1.csv', 'r')

#list of lines in midvalues1.csv
csv_data = csv.readlines()

#close csv to avoid data loss.
csv.close()


#replace all commas with spaces in midvalues1.csv
for i in range(len(csv_data)):
    csv_data[i] = csv_data[i].replace(',', '    ')

#Iterate thru txt_data
for i, x in enumerate(txt_data):

    #Iterate thru csv_data
    for j, y in enumerate(csv_data):

        #found = False if not found
        found = 0
        if x in y:

            #found turns True if found
            found = 1
            print(y)
            print('Found !')

            #new_file's name should be ident{i+1}
            new_file_name = f'ident{i+1}'

            #create a new_file with the name given
            new_file = open(new_file_name, 'w')

            #write lines
            new_file.writelines(y)

            #close the file for saving
            new_file.close()

    #If not found print 'Data not Found'
    if found == 0:
        print(f'{x} is not found!')
```